# How to disable `@EnableKafka` in Spring Boot tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-boot-test

I would like to run my integration tests but I don't know how to disable `@EnableKafka`.

My app looks like that:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafka
public class MyApplication {
```

Comment: You can use @Embeddedkafka annotation or EmbeddedKafkaRule?

Comment: @Hatice I want to do the opposite - in my test I don't need kafka thus - I want to have a way to easily disable it.

Comment: You don't need `@EnableKafka` there - Boot automatically configures it for you if spring-kafka is on the classpath; so it's redundant there. To disable it for a test you need to disable auto configuration for kafka. Refer to the [Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Spring Boot come with an auto-configuration for Spring Kafka, therefore you don't need to use an explicit `@EnableKafka`. What you need to do in your test is just exclude `KafkaAutoConfiguration`:

```
@SpringBootTest("spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration")
```

Answer (score 9):

You can create another config file for your Kafka configuration.

```
@ConditionalOnProperty("kafka.enabled")
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration { }
```

like that and then you can disable this property in your test.properties file.

Check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54426658/control-enabling-disabling-kafka-consumers-in-spring-boot?rq=1)

Answer (score 6):

You can disable the autoconfiguration of Kafka with this Spring annotation:

`@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {KafkaAutoConfiguration.class})`