# Spring boot enable/disable tomcat or kafka consumer based on the profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-profiles

I'm writing a Spring Boot application with several @Configuration classes for rest APIs and for Kafka consumers/producers depending on which @Profile it chooses to initialize.

The first configuration class uses the REST interface, and I have these dependencies added.
This starts up an embedded Tomcat instance and runs fine.

Here the problem is the other profiles should not spin a tomcat server, it should act only as a Kafka consumer.

Is there any way to stop spinning the @SpringBootApplication from starting up Tomcat based on profiles?

I created 2 configuration classes, one for Kafka and one for rest endpoints, and added @Profile annotation for each config class. Can someone guide me on how to stop spin tomcat from my app?

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Main application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(value = {RestScanConfiguration.class, KafkaScanConfiguration.class})
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

RestScanConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "package.app.rest")
@Profile("!kafka")
public class RestScanConfiguration {
}
```

KafkaScanConfiguration class:

```
 @Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(
        exclude = {
                DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
                HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
                ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class
        })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"package.app.kafka"})
@Profile("kafka")
public class KafkaScanConfiguration {
}
```

can someone guide me on this?

How to stop spinning the tomcat server in Kafka consumer/producer profile. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Here the problem is the other profiles should not spin a tomcat server, it should act only as a Kafka consumer" - how do you plan on running the consumer, if not on a tomcat server or any other server?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to disbale the auto configuration for the embeded tomcat in the starter class to avoid deploying the tomcat:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class, 
                                  WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

and then add the following property to your kafka config (non-Rest profiles):

```
spring.main.web-environment=false
```

now you have disabled auto-deployment of the integrated tomcat in spring boot. Now add the following configuration to your Rest profile to enable tomcat (only for this profile):

```
@Profile({"REST"})
@Configuration
// importing EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration delays the autoconfiguration until the profile load into context
@Import(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class)
public class HttpConfiguration {
    // ...
}
```

and afterwards you have configure your kafka dynamically. You can find a solution for that in [Control enabling/disabling Kafka consumers in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54426658/control-enabling-disabling-kafka-consumers-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of configuring this in code I'd suggest you to create `application-kafka.properties` (or `application-kafka.yml`) and add the following line into it:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration
```

This disables `ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration` which is a root configuration class for Web environment.

`-kafka` suffix in properties file name tells Spring to pick it up only when `kafka` profile is active.

Even better solution is to exclude

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

from built jar. In other words you could have a `pom.xml` two profiles with only required dependencies (shared ones are located in main `dependencies` section). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/167284/12473843. Using this approach you don't even need specifying excluded autoconfigurations as without `spring-boot-starter-web` in the classpath corresponding started is never activated.

Answer (score 0):

Similar kind of issue I faced, while starting Kafka consumer it's starting tomcat on 8080 port and with another consumer start it was failing with error "Port already in use"

Appearently previously same code working on spring boot 2.2 version when upgraded to higher version 2.6 it was showing above port in use error.

Below pom exclusion worked for me.

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```